# PayPal INSTRUMENT_DECLINED error after switching to Live application when using Guest flow

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

When I try to execute an approved PayPal payment that was done using the guest flow, rather than logging in to an existing PayPal account (which works fine). The error INSTRUMENT_DECLINED is received.

I've used multiple payment cards, they all have sufficient funding. Even the same ones used when logging in to a PayPal account don't work, but work fine when connected to a PayPal account.

The full response is as follows:

```
[18-08-2017 11:44:53] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: POST https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXXXX/execute
[18-08-2017 11:44:56] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Response Status  : 400
[18-08-2017 11:44:56] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : ERROR: Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXXXX/execute. {"name":"INSTRUMENT_DECLINED","details":[],"message":"The instrument presented  was either declined by the processor or bank, or it can't be used for this payment.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"XXXX"}
```

PayPal account response:

```
[18-08-2017 12:45:27] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Response Status  : 200
[18-08-2017 12:45:27] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: POST https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXXX/execute
```

Sandbox response:

```
[18-08-2017 01:24:17] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: Response Status  : 200
[18-08-2017 01:24:17] PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection : INFO: POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXXX/execute
```

It almost seems as though guest checkout requires some configuration to enable guest checkout, that's linked to the live API key or something to that respect. I've checked everywhere but I can't find anything that would make any difference.

I'm also using the PHP SDK. Not sure if that would be the cause, or there's something involved in it which would cause this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I am having the same error response from PayPal. For me though, is happening when I am using the live api. It is happening either when I am trying to pay with a paypal acount or a card (as a guest). When I am using the sandbox everything is working fine. The balance of my card is sufficient. Have you found any solutions? Thank you

Comment: I've since had this issue when using a card linked to a PayPal account as well, but we have other test accounts where it works. So it seems as though there's some sort of verification required - or the account / card needs to be in a specific state of approval to be accepted by the API Key / Account. Just a wild guess based on the behaviour though. Unfortunately I'm no closer to resolving this issue. I asked PayPal support for assistance on Friday, but not yet had a response. Will post any updates I have.